Hermite Polynomial and its Expectation
Currently, I'm stuck to some statement in a paper (in chapter 8: Nonlinear Model, from page 26 ~27). Although this topic generally covers statistics and machine learning theory, my main question is generally on pure math. I summarized the contents where I'm stuck

Consider a function $\varphi : \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb E[\varphi(G)]=0$ and $\mathbb E[G\varphi(G)] = 0$ for $G\sim N(0,1)$. Denote the $\varphi$ using Hermite polynomials as follows:
$$\varphi(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\lambda_k(\varphi)h_k(t).$$
Suppose $z\in\mathbb R^d$ has i.i.d entries from $N(0,1)$, $W \in \mathbb R^{p\times d}$ has i.i.d entries such that $\|w_i\| = 1$, where $w_i^T$ is the $i$th row of $W$. Then, we have
$$\mathbb E[\varphi(w_i^Tz)\varphi(w_j^Tz)|W] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\lambda_k^2(\varphi)(w_i^Tw_j)^k,\tag{1}$$
Also, using the property $\lambda_0(\varphi) = \mathbb E[G]= 0$ and $\lambda_1(\varphi) =\mathbb E[G\varphi(G)] =0$, we conclude that
$$\mathbb E[\varphi(w_i^Tz)\varphi(w_j^Tz)|W] = O((w_i^Tw_j)^2) = O(1/d).\tag{2}$$

Since this paper is from statistics, I will regard the Hermite polynomial as probabilist's one. When $W$ is given, $y_i := w_i^Tz \sim N(0,1)$. Then, (considering $i=1,j=2$ wlog),
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb E[\varphi(w_1^Tz)\varphi(w_2^Tz)|W] &= \mathbb E[\varphi(y_1)\varphi(y_2)] \\
&= \int\int\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\lambda_k(\varphi)\lambda_l(\varphi)h_k(y_1)h_l(y_2)f(y_1,y_2)d(y_1,y_2),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $f$ is some joint pdf of $y_1,y_2$. I was stuck to here because I'm not sure whether this approach is correct.  Since $y_1, y_2$ share $z$, they are not necessarily independent and $f$ can't be decomposed as a product of  two distinct normal pdf.
Also, regarding (2), how can I get the result $\lambda_0(\varphi) = 0$ and $\lambda_1(\varphi) = 0$? Based on the definition of Hermite polynomial, my calculation goes as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
\lambda_0(\varphi) &= \frac{1}{0!}\int\varphi(t)h_0(t)e^{-t^2/2}dt \\
&= \frac{1}{0!}\int \underbrace{h_0(t)^2}_{:=1\text{ by def}}e^{-t^2/2}dt \\
&\neq 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
So I can't conclude that the two Hermitian coefficients are zero respectively (because similar results occurs for $\lambda_1$).
Any help regarding the above two questions would be grateful. Thank you.
